# Oracle Materialized View - Need help in creating View with very large number of records

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

We have to create a materialised view in our database from a remote database which is currently in production. The view has about 5 crore records and is taking a long time. In between , the connection has snapped once and not even a single record persisted in our database. Since the remote database is production server, we get a very limited window to create the view.

My question is, can we have something like auto commit /auto start from where left at last time while the view is created so that we don't have to do the entire operation in one go ?

We are tying to make the query such that records can be fetched in smaller numbers as a alternate. But the data is read only for us and doesn't really have a where clause at this point which we can use.

Due to sensitive nature of data, I cannot post the view structure or the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not commit during the process of creating the view. But why don't you import the data to a table instead of a view? This would provide the possibility to commit in between. Furthermore this might provide the possibility, to load only the delta of changes maybe on daily basis - this would reduce the required time dramatically.